# Magento -> Is this an anonymous function?

Tags: magento-1.4

We have a lot of code in our codebase that was done by a third-party developer. They modified many places in the core and we wanted to figure out exactly what is happening.

They have code like this:

```
$pidsess = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
$pidsess->setNA_pid(array("PID" => $pid, "PartInfo" => $return_data['result']));
```

What this does is store a "globally available variable" that can be called at anytime the Magento Session is alive like this:

```
$pidsess = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
$piddata = $pidsess->getNA_pid();
```

Where can I find the code that is setting this "variable"? I have searched for 'setNA_' and found several calls but none of them the actual function call.

Is this a part of Magento's stupid EAV architecture where you can make up your own functions to set EAV values? If so, where would the values be stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling something stupid just because you didn't have time to understand and/or didn't like it certainly isn't going to help. However, as with many magento base classes, it probably just sets a variable into the magento session that ends somewhere in the session storage.

I'd start with `Mage::log(print_r($_SESSION,1)` to see if there is really an `['NA_pid']`.

And it has nothing to do with EAV.

Comment: Session storage will either be a file named with the session ID or an entry in a table if you've set Magento to store sessions in the database.

Comment: In my opinion, using EAV for this product was the dumbest thing to do because you have to travel 100 miles to go across the street.    If it is as simple as putting it in the session, why can I not find anything about using this "functionality" anywhere in any documentation?

Comment: It seems that it IS putting an entry into the session called n_a_pid. I just wished it had been documented SOMEWHERE...But I guess it's par for the course for Magento, keep everything as clandestine as possible! God, I can't wait to dump this piece of crap next month.

Comment: It's par for the course of a low paid developer who's creating a one time knockoff custom modification. Having them document their mods obviously wasn't part of the spec on development. And core mods instead of custom modules speaks for itself and the quality of hire.